# Why does git checkout <remote_branchname> not create new tracking branch?

Tags: git, version-control

*TLDR*: If X exists as a remote branch, then `git checkout X` should create a local branch of it. In my case, for a single branch, it does not.

The remote repository has a `master,` `release,` and some other branches (say `refactor-update`)
I do:

`git clone WHATEVER/repo.git`
`git checkout release`

But I do not get the normal branch switch message, nor is a local branch tracking `origin/release` created (per the `man` page for `git checkout`). I am still on `master.` Note that if I do `git checkout refactor-update` everything works as expected.

This is reproducible on other computers (though the same platform and likely the same version of git). I have (out of desperation, not because I thought it would work), removed the `release` branch and replaced it with a backup and `master` respectively with no change in behaviour (`git push origin :release && git push origin master:release`)

I am stuck for what might be causing the problem. My suspicion is that `git checkout` doesn't seem to recognize the word `release` for some reason, which would make it much like executing just `git checkout`. To try and follow up on this, in another repo I created a release branch to see if it was a reserved word or something, but it is definitely just in this repository. There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary in `.git/config`.

Git version: 1.8

Comment: Did you forget to fetch the remote branches maybe? Try a `git fetch --prune` and then the same `git checkout X`

Comment: I have tried `git fetch` but not with `--prune`. Doesn't this just remove remote branches which no longer exist from my local?

Comment: Yes, `-p` / `--prune` only adds the "remove unmatched" behavior, the pick-up stuff is always enabled (well, provided you have not broken the git config `fetch =` line for the remote :-) ).

Comment: `--prune` didn't have different behaviour than normal `fetch.` I tried to create a nearly empty repo with no private info to provide as a reproduction step and then the release branch started working. Sadly, I have no use for a repo in which I deleted all the files and replaced them with an empty `TESTFILE` :P

Comment: As an experiment I executed `gitk somebranchonlyontheremote` and as expected gitk says 'wut?' I then did `gitk release` (with no local branch named `release`) and it showed me a history...

Comment: Does the root folder of your project contain a file or folder with the same name as the branch that you want to check out? That is, is there a file/folder `repo/release`? That was part of the problem for me. Which version of git are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git checkout master does not switch branch - repository broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287722/git-checkout-master-does-not-switch-branch-repository-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the problem is that I have a folder with the same name as the branch in the root of my project. Git seems to think the `xyz` in `git checkout xyz` is the folder, not the branch.

I had to do the following to switch my working tree to branch `xyz` for the first time:

`git checkout -t origin/xyz`

Apparently, this adds a few lines to `.git/config` (and maybe other configuration files). After that, I can switch between `xyz` and `master` just by calling `git checkout xyz` / `git checkout master`.

When I'm in the root folder and call `git checkout xyz` right after I cloned the repo, git does nothing and doesn't give any response either. When I `cd` to a sub-folder so that the folder `xyz` is not in scope anymore and then call `git checkout xyz`, git complains: `error: pathspec 'xyz' did not match any file(s) known to git`.

Comment: That looks like a bug -- you should write up a reproducer and send a bug report in to the git mailing list.

Comment: I just tried again with git version 1.7.9.5 on a different system - same behavior. Either I misunderstand / misremember how `git checkout xyz` is supposed to work, or GitHub has made some strange changes since I last cloned my repo. :-(

Comment: What do you mean by "magic DWIM for `-b`"? I just tried `git checkout -b  xyz` on 1.8.3.2, and it just creates a new branch without a connection to the remote branch.

Comment: I edited my answer: the problem is caused by a folder that has the same name as the branch. With a branch for which no such folder exists, `git checkout foo` works as expected.

Comment: I mean, the fancy "oh wow that's a branch name not a path name" thing (where you don't need `-b`).  I'm always leery of DWIM in the first place, it leads to situations like the one you ran into where a branch name and a path element match.

Comment: @torek on the other hand, checking out pathnames without the `--` separator is just as much a DWIM, but I'd hate to lose it.

Comment: @jthill: lucky for you I'm not in charge of git commands, perhaps. :-)  I'd probably split "checkout" into at least two completely different commands, one to "switch to (optionally creating) branch" and one to "extract file(s) from current or named branch".

Comment: It might be a bug, but it is the correct answer. I removed the `release` folder and now `git checkout release` works as expected. @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt, @torek: thanks for staying on this and assuming I'm not a git newbie who has never seen the `-b` or `-t` arguments.

Comment: It's a bug and the fixes are being bandied-about on the git email list.  There's disagreement whether `git checkout x` means *branch* `x` or *path* `x` when both are possible, but `git checkout x --` should *definitely* mean "branch `x`" and it's just broken.

Answer (score 1):

Clone gives you remotes for all the origin's branches, but it only gives you a local branch for the origin's `HEAD` branch (or any other branch on request).

> TLDR: If X exists as a remote branch, then git checkout X should create a local branch of it. In my case, for a single branch, it does not.

I'll venture to disagree with that.  If you want checkout to create a branch, tell it to create a 
branch.

```
git checkout -t origin/release     # create branch `release` tracking `origin/release`.

git checkout -b foobar             # create branch `foobar` based on your HEAD commit
```

---

[edit:]

I think I understand the complaint now.

`git checkout name` does:

- if it's local branch or explicit remote branch, switch to it.
- if it's a tracked path, reset it
- if it's a remote branch, create a tracking branch and switch to it.

and because it prioritizes the reset it can choose to do something unsafe when it could have chosen to do something safe.

Comment: The confusing thing is that `git checkout foo` usually *does* check out the remote branch - unless there is a file/folder called `foo`. So I'll venture to disagree with your disagreement. ;-)

Comment: live and learn.  A remote breaking my path checkouts by adding a bad branch name alarms me as much as breaking that nifty implicit-tracking-branch-creation checkout with a bad pathname alarms you.  I agree with @torek's comment, this behavior is so unpredictable it's in bug territory.  git should warn when both conveniences might apply rather than silently picking the one I like.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-b` option

Try doing

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

***Edit Note***: As discussed in comments below, this would be the case only if you were using git version 1.7.9 or lesser, which I had been at the time.

Comment: Is the `-b` option necessary even if the branch exists remotely?

Comment: @Miguelgraz  `git checkout branch_name` will switch between branches only if they exist locally. Since the branch does not exist on your local repo, you need the `-b` flag to create a branch and switch to it in one go.

Comment: Actually, it depends on your particular version of git.  With quite new versions, you don't need `-b` anymore, git auto-detects that you don't have a `foo` branch but there is a `remotes/origin/foo` so it does an implied `-b foo origin/foo`.

Comment: @torek can you tell the particular versions beyond which this works? I seem to have an older copy, and same could be true for OP :)

Comment: @ansh0l: Note I said "per the man page for git checkout" which specifically states my use case should work. Not only that I outline how my use case works for other branches.

In my case I am running something in the 1.8 branch.

Comment: I saw this in the 1.8.3.2 release notes.  The 1.6.1 release notes mention adding `git checkout --track origin/hack` as a way to create the local branch `hack`, too, but 1.8.3 is probably the first one to do it by just naming the remote branch without `origin/`.

Comment: `git checkout -b x` doesn't work for me (git 1.8.3.2 on a Mac). It says `Switched to a new branch 'x'` but doesn't change the working tree. If I add the branch to .git/config first, git says `Switched to a new branch 'x'` but also `Your branch and 'origin/x' have diverged` and tells me to do `git pull`. When I run `git pull`, git tries to merge branch x into my local copy of the master branch, which results in a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `-t` option.

```
git checkout -t origin/release
```

will create and check out the local branch `release` that tracks `origin/release`.

With newer versions of Git, this is enough:

```
git checkout release
```