# Git change branch when file of same name is present

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have in my git repo, a file named xyz. Coincidently, I also have a branch named xyz. Presently I am on master, but I want to checkout to branch xyz. The command to be used is simple

```
$ git checkout xyz
```

But this would checkout the file `xyz` to the present HEAD. How would I change my branch to branch `xyz`?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

As illustrated by [commit a047faf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a047fafc7866cc4087201e284dc1f53e8f9a32d5) (git 1.8.4.3+), you can also try:

```
git checkout xyz --
```

(Note: the [error message will be clearer with Git 2.21, Q1 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058395/6309))

That would make clear that the `xyz` part is a branch or commit, while  everything after `--` must be a path (here no path is provided). See [more here on the double-hyphen convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309).

If you try without the '`--`', that might or might not work, as shown in "[Why does git checkout `<remote_branchname>` not create new tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18995918/6309)":

> `git checkout name` does:
>
> - if it's local branch or explicit remote branch, switch to it.
> - if it's a tracked path, reset it
> - if it's a remote branch, create a tracking branch and switch to it.

And its behavior isn't always the same. Hence the '`--`' to provide a clear disambiguation.

---

Update August 2019, Git 2.23+

[`git checkout` is too confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) and is replaced with:

- **[`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)**: meaning `git switch xyz` will work even if you have a file `xyz`,
- **[`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)**: meaning `git restore xyz` will work even if you have a branch `xyz`.

Plus, as I explain in "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)", no more unexpected detached HEAD.

Comment: Better solution, IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537923/1096596

Comment: @BobbyA I have updated the answer with an even better answer

Comment: Why not `git checkout -- docs`? [OpenGroup Guideline 10](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) talks about `--` as the *end of options argument*, but I don't understand why it works at the end of that command, but not **before** `docs`.

Comment: @FernandoBasso In the answer, `xyz` is the name of a branch, not a path, hence the `--` *after* `xyz`. But nowadays, you would not ask your self that question: using `git switch` (branch only) or `git restore` (path/file only) solve that. `git checkout` is obsolete and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 10):

While VonC's solution works, I can never remember the syntax, so I typically use a more low-tech solution:

```
$ (cd somedir && git checkout my-branch)
```

Or, if you don't have any subdirectories:

```
$ (cd .git && git -C .. checkout my-branch)
```

It's easier to remember and it works ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Git 2.21 (Q1 2019, 4+ years later) will **clarify the error message and make suggestions**

"`git checkout frotz`" ([without any double-dash that I suggested initially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322508/6309)) **avoids ambiguity by making sure '`frotz`' cannot be interpreted as a revision and as a path at the same time**.

This safety has been updated to check also a unique remote-tracking branch '`frotz`' in a remote, when [dwimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) to create a local branch '`frotz`' out of a remote-tracking branch '`frotz`' from a remote.

Note: ["dwim" (used below) is "do what I mean"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM), when a computer system attempts to anticipate what users intend to do, correcting trivial errors automatically rather than blindly executing users' explicit but potentially incorrect inputs.

See [commit be4908f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d) (13 Nov 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8d7f9db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d7f9dbf84fca7158dbbc69af1ac4002396a4d9a), 04 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `checkout`: disambiguate dwim tracking branches and local files

> When checkout dwim is added in [commit 70c9ac2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4), it is restricted to only dwim when certain conditions are met and fall back to default checkout behavior otherwise.
>
> It turns out falling back could be confusing.
>
> One of the conditions to turn
>
> ```
> git checkout frotz
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> git checkout -b frotz origin/frotz
> ```
>
> is that `frotz` must not exist as a file.
>
> But when the user comes to expect "`git checkout frotz`" to create the branch "`frotz`" and there happens to be a file named "`frotz`", **git's silently reverting "`frotz`" file content is not helping**.
> This is reported in [Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CACsJy8B2TVr1g+k+eSQ=pBEO3WN4_LtgLo9gpur8X7Z9GOFL_A@mail.gmail.com/) and even used as [an example of "Git is bad" elsewhere](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18230655).
>
> We normally try to do the right thing, but when there are multiple "right things" to do, it's best to leave it to the user to decide.
>
> Check this case, ask the user to to disambiguate:
>
> - "`git checkout -- foo`" will check out path "foo"
> - "`git checkout foo --`" will dwim and create branch "`foo`" [6](http://70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4)
>
> For users who do not want dwim, use `--no-guess`. It's useless in this
> particular case because "`git checkout --no-guess foo --`" will just fail.
> But it could be used by scripts.

The [man page for `git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L279-L281) now includes:

> ```
> --no-guess:
> ```
>
> Do not attempt to create a branch if a remote tracking branch of the same name exists.

---

Before Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "[`git checkout  X`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)" did not correctly fail when `X` is not a local branch but **could name more than one remote-tracking branches** (i.e. to be dwimmed as the starting point to create a corresponding local branch), which has been corrected.

See [commit fa74180](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa74180d08e0a82bdae0c127a009b055c603b11a), [commit 2957709](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2957709bd44a5b18d180ba4c3864a431a5aaed38) (30 Dec 2019) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d0e70cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0e70cd32e95df3be2250536f9089c858a298874), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa74180d08e0a82bdae0c127a009b055c603b11a): don't revert file on ambiguous tracking branches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>

> For easier understanding, here are the existing good scenarios:
>
> 1. Have *no* file '`foo`', *no* local branch '`foo`' and a *single* remote branch '`foo`'
> 2. `git checkout foo` will create local branch `foo`, see [commit 70c9ac2 above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4), [discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/7vaazpxha4.fsf_-_@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/).
>
> and
>
> 1. Have *a* file '`foo`', *no* local branch '`foo`' and a *single* remote branch '`foo`'
> 2. `git checkout foo` will complain, see [commit be4908f above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d)
>
> This patch prevents the following scenario:
>
> 1. Have *a* file '`foo`', *no* local branch '`foo`' and *multiple* remote branches '`foo`'
> 2. `git checkout foo` will successfully... revert contents of file `foo`!
>
> That is, adding another remote suddenly changes behavior significantly, which is a surprise at best and could go unnoticed by user at worst.
> Please see [commit be4908f above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d), which gives some real world complaints.
>
> To my understanding, fix in [commit be4908f above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d) ([discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/20181110120707.25846-1-pclouds@gmail.com/)), overlooked the case of multiple remotes, and the whole behavior of falling back to reverting file was never intended:
>
> - [commit 70c9ac2 above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4) introduces the unexpected behavior.
>   Before, there was fallback from not-a-ref to pathspec. This is reasonable fallback.
>   After, there is another fallback from ambiguous-remote to pathspec.
>   I understand that it was a copy&paste oversight.
> - [commit ad8d510](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad8d5104b42108851b082d895018655ad5f9e4f3), from "[Can't do a checkout with multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714521/6309)", and [discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/20180502105452.17583-1-avarab@gmail.com/), noticed the unexpected behavior but chose to semi-document it instead of forbidding, because the goal of the patch series was focused on something else.
> - [commit be4908f above](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be4908f1038861892878db29441be5a4a024784d) adds `die()` when there is ambiguity between branch and file.
>   The case of multiple tracking branches is seemingly overlooked.
>
> **The new behavior: if there is no local branch and multiple remote candidates, just `die()` and don't try reverting file whether it exists (prevents surprise) or not (improves error message)**.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0e41cfad622dde07815d3d575fd3bf05db83da32/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> learned to use **`checkout.guess`** configuration variable and enable/disable its "`--[no-]guess`" option accordingly.

See [commit 64f1f58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64f1f58fe7c0837bd0ae56ba83add5e1b84c54d3) (07 Oct 2020), and [commit ef09e7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef09e7ddf3e77960ea24ea1580439fb725b4063a) (06 Oct 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0e41cfa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e41cfad622dde07815d3d575fd3bf05db83da32), 27 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64f1f58fe7c0837bd0ae56ba83add5e1b84c54d3): learn to respect `checkout.guess`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> The current behavior of `git checkout/switch` is that `--guess` is currently enabled by default.
> However, some users may not wish for this to happen automatically.
> Instead of forcing users to specify `--no-guess` manually each time, teach these commands the `checkout.guess` configuration variable that gives users the option to set a default behavior.
>
> Teach the completion script to recognize the new config variable and disable [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) logic if it is set to false.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64f1f58fe7c0837bd0ae56ba83add5e1b84c54d3/Documentation/config/checkout.txt#L19-L23):

> ### `checkout.guess`
>
> Provides the default value for the `--guess` or `--no-guess`
> option in `git checkout` and `git switch`. See
> [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) and [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

`git checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64f1f58fe7c0837bd0ae56ba83add5e1b84c54d3/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L195-L198):

> `--guess` is the default behavior. Use `--no-guess` to disable it.
>
> The default behavior can be set via the `checkout.guess` configuration
> variable.

`git switch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64f1f58fe7c0837bd0ae56ba83add5e1b84c54d3/Documentation/git-switch.txt#L106-L108):

> The default behavior can be set via the `checkout.guess` configuration
> variable.

Answer (score -3):

You're wrong. It will checkout branch xyz.

To checkout a file, you need to use command `git checkout -- xyz`.
Git just allow you a shortcut for files if there is no branch with the same name.

See `git checkout --help` for details.

Comment: Why would I ask the question if it doesn't happen? I is happening to me. Generally on checking out a branch, the response is `Switched to branch 'xyz'`, but in my case, there was no response. Which is the usual scenario when checking out a file. Also, I have seen the output of `git branch -va` to conclude that no such change has occurred.