# "git checkout --" . vs git checkout

Tags: git

I always used `git checkout -- .` to clear my working directory. I thought I read somewhere that the `--` was required to avoid git thinking you are passing parameters (or something)

Now a colleague told me I could drop the `--`, and indeed, a quick test did exactly the same.

Is there are any difference between those two commands?

PS: Asking here because `git checkout -- .` vs `git checkout .` is kind of hard to google...

Comment: Where did you read this? Have you read the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I seem to recall that the `--` is a way to tell Git to treat what follows `checkout` as a file and not as a branch.  Suppose that you had both a file and a branch called `stuff`.  Then the following command would seem ambiguous:

```
git checkout stuff
```

because it is not clear whether you are asking to checkout a file or a branch.  By using `--` you explicitly tell Git to checkout a file by that name/path.  So in this case the following commands allow checking out a branch and a file called `stuff`:

```
git checkout stuff       # checkout the branch stuff
git checkout -- stuff    # checkout the file stuff
```

Note that `git checkout <name>` is really meant for branches, but Git syntax is relaxed, and if Git can't find a branch, then it will look for a file.

Closely related: [Git change branch when file of same name is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322335/git-change-branch-when-file-of-same-name-is-present)

Comment: I really did mean `git co .` aka `git reset HEAD --hard`. But I guess I've been typing those two dashes superfluously for the past 2 years :)

Comment: @Laoujin `git co .` is definitely not *aka* `git reset --hard`. Those two commands do different things.

Answer (score 37):

`--` as a standalone argument (i.e. not part of another argument) is used by many UNIX command line programs to indicate that anything that follows it is not an argument.

Why?  Well, in this case, it's being used in case you have a path whose name starts with `--`, which shouldn't be interpreted as its own argument.

i.e. `git checkout -- --mydirectory` which, without the `--` would throw an error.