# Does the `git checkout --` command have anything to do with the `--` argument of bash?

Tags: bash, git, arguments

I was attempting to export a bash environment variable of a path with a dash in it when I came across the [-- argument of bash](https://serverfault.com/a/462740/1980).  I noticed that it's seemly similar to [how one checks out a single file of some version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101998/git-checkout-vs-git-checkout) in in `git`.

Is there any relation between the two, are they the same thing, do they severe the same purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--` is not anything specific to `bash`; it is a *convention* that many commands follow when processing their arguments. The convention is that no argument appearing after `--` should be treated as an option, even if there is an option by that name.

This convention is recommended as Guideline #10 in the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02).