# Foreign key rejected despite columns having different data types

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to set up two tables in a database, and add a foreign key between them. They're declared as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `clothing` (
  `name` varchar(26) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `localized_name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`localized_name`)),
  `main` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `stars` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `splatnet` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`splatnet`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `abilities` (
  `name` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `localized_name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`localized_name`))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I want to create a foreign key on `clothing` that references `abilities` with the following command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `abilities` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`name`) REFERENCES `clothing` (`main`);
```

However, attempting to do this raises this error in return:

```
Source and target columns must have the same data type, there must be an index on the target columns and referenced data must exist.
Can't create table `prismarine_rusted`.`abilities` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this, and unless I'm overlooking something *really* obvious, `main` and `name` have the same type, and therefore, should be able to be tied together via a foreign key. I'm using MariaDB v10.4.12, with SQL mode set to `TRADITIONAL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the foreign and primary key columns involved here are the same type, you are trying to reference `clothing.main`, which is not a unique or primary key column.  From the MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/):

> The referenced columns must be a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index.

Note that this differs from InnoDB on MySQL, where a foreign key column can in fact reference a non unique column in another table.

One way to remedy this error would be to make `clothing.main` a unique column:

```
ALTER TABLE clothing ADD UNIQUE (main);
```

Note that doing this might only make logical sense if the values in `main` are already unique.  If not, then perhaps you would have to revisit your data model.

Comment: Not to mention the error message even says right there that the columns have to be indexed.

Comment: @Powerlord I remember you [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101998/git-checkout-vs-git-checkout/41102213#41102213).

Answer (score 0):

It might be because there is a value in abilities.name that has no match in the referenced table.