# git checkout branch shows wrong state

Tags: git

`git branch -a` shows me

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/origin/feature
```

I want to checkout the last branch `remotes/origin/origin/feature`.

I don't really know why there is `remotes/origin/feature` and  `remotes/origin/origin/feature` they were created by someone else.

The structure looks like this

```
         --> F --> G        origin/feature
       /
A --> B --> C --> D --> E   master
```

Now I want to merge `remotes/origin/origin/feature` into master.

Strangley, If I want to checkout the feature branch using

```
git checkout 'origin/feature'
```

all files are at the state from point `B` and not at point `G`. I triggered the merge via the gitlab GUI and it told me I have to use

`git checkout -b 'origin/feature' 'origin/feature'`

This worked, now all files are at the stage of `G`.
Why is this so? Why do I have to use the `-b` option even if the branch already exists and why do I have to enter it twice?

Answer (score 2):

First, do not use `git checkout`, which is obsolete and replaced with [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).
Or at least use `git checkout origin/feature --` to force git checkout to consider `origin/feature` as a branch name, not a file, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322508/6309).
(Hence `git switch`, which only deals with branches, not branches or files, like git `checkout` does)

Second:

> Why do I have to use the `-b` option even if the branch already exists and why do I have to enter it twice

Because the branch exists only as a remote tracking branch (a memento of what was last fetched from the remote named `origin`)

It is best to *not* include `origin/xxx` in the name of the branch, because it is confusing since the default remote repository is itself named `origin`.

A simple `git switch origin/feature` is enough, because it has a [guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Besides [VonC's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74077561/1256452) (which is good: use `git switch` to avoid some of the confusion), it's worth noting that `remotes/origin/feature` and `remotes/origin/origin/feature` are not actually *branch* names.  Git's terminology here is awful: it is confusing and not always consistent.

To make sense of this, you need to know several things about Git:

- It's actually the *commits* that matter.  A name—whether it is a branch name, or a tag name, or some other kind of name entirely—exists so that you and Git can *find the hash ID* of the commit.  The hash ID, that big ugly string of letters and digits like [`d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376), is the true name of the commit, but *humans are bad at hash IDs*.  We like simple names like `main` or `next` or `v2.37.0` or whatever.
- So, Git provides names.  These come in a long list of flavors.  Branch names are just one of those flavors.
- You can have a *branch* `xyzzy` **and** a *tag* `xyzzy`.  You probably shouldn't—it's very confusing when you do this—but you *can* do it.  So Git needs to know how to tell a branch name from a tag name, for instance.
- The method Git uses to know this is to give everything a "full name" (like a person's full name: "J Robert Oppenheimer"), and to use a shortened name for more familiar usage (e.g., "Bob").

To categorize the names, Git sticks them in a [*namespace:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) all *branch* names start with `refs/heads/`, and then the rest of the string is the branch name, so `master` is actually short for `refs/heads/master`.  All *tag* names start with `refs/tags/`, so if you were to create a tag named `master`, it would be `refs/tags/master`.  Don't do this: *Git* can keep them straight internally by sticking the prefixes back on, but you probably won't.

Now, one particular, and slightly weird, name-flavor is the *remote-tracking name*.<sup>1</sup>  A remote-tracking name is a name (of course) in your own Git repository, and it actually starts with `refs/remotes/`.  Git leaves out the `refs/`, and sometimes also the `remotes/` part as well:

> ```
> $ git branch -a
> * master
>   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   remotes/origin/feature
>   remotes/origin/master
>   remotes/origin/origin/feature
> ```

Had you run `git branch -r`, Git would not have listed `* master` at all, and would have taken `remotes/` off the remaining names, leaving:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/feature
origin/master
origin/origin/feature
```

Again, these are all remote-tracking names.  They *really* are spelled "refs/remotes/origin/whatever".  Git is just shortening them by leaving off "refs/" or "refs/remotes/", and you can do that too.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has, over the years, not been entirely consistent in what *Git* calls these, but modern Git tries to use the phrase "remote-tracking branch name" pretty consistently now.  I don't like the insertion of "branch" here: I think it's actually *less* confusing to *leave it out*.  So that's what I do, but know that Git sticks it in.  Pay particular attention to the "remote-tracking" part, as that's the real clue.

---

#### Remote-tracking names and where they come from

Every Git repository is independent of all other Git repositories, even if they're linked and yours is a clone of some other existing repository.  So every Git repository has *its own* branch names.  You have *your* `master`, Joe has Joe's `master`, Sally has Sally's `master`, Ramesh has Ramesh's `master`, and so on.

When you cloned the repository you're using, *they* had a branch named `master` too.  Your Git refers to that repository as `origin`.  So your Git took their name `master`—technically, `refs/heads/master`—and *changed it* to `origin/master`, or technically `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  So their `master`, a *branch* name, became your `origin/master`, a *remote-tracking name*.

Your Git software did that for *every* branch name that their Git software said that they have in their repository.  So that tells us that, given the list of `origin/*` names that `git branch -a` showed, *they* have `HEAD`, `feature`, `master`, and—here's the weird one—`origin/feature`.  That's a *branch* name in their Git repository, whose full name is `refs/heads/origin/master`.  **Their Git software and your Git software always use the full name internally so that they don't get confused about this.**  But your Git software *shows you* your *abbreviated* names.  Your Git created a `refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature` to match their *branch* named `origin/feature`, and your Git now shows that as either `origin/origin/feature` (after taking off `refs/remotes/`) or `remotes/origin/origin/feature` (after taking off only `refs/`).

#### Checkout vs switch

The `git checkout` command lets you use both *branch* names **and** remote-tracking names.  If you put something in that's ambiguous, `git checkout` has rules by which it figures out what you mean.  Confusingly, both `git checkout` and `git switch` have modes that will *create a new branch name*, and this interacts with the "figuring out" rules in weird and wonderful (or terrible) ways.  Because `git switch` has *simpler* rules, the interactions are not as [wacky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wacky).  Unfortunately for you, *someone else* goofed up and set up a situation where *you* get to experience at least a little bit of wackiness no matter what you do.

The rules for `git checkout` go roughly like this (although they're actually considerably more complicated):

1. Try something as a branch name: do we have a branch with that name?  If so, use that as our existing branch name.
2. Try something as, in order, a tag name, a remote-tracking name, or a general-purpose name.  Do we have that name as that kind of name?  If so, use that as a *non-branch* name.
3. If none of those worked and `--guess` mode is in effect, proceed into the "guess and create new branch if possible" code.  (This used to be called "DWIM mode", and still is in older Git documentation.)

The middle rule here, step 2, allows you to check out any specific commit as a *detached HEAD*.  The `git switch` command won't do that unless you add `--detach` to the arguments.

Because `origin/feature` *is* a remote-tracking name in your repository, your `git checkout` takes it up if and when it hits step 2 (but not if it finds `origin/feature` as a *branch* name in your repository in step 1).  But `origin/origin/feature` is *also* a remote-tracking name in your repository, so you could `git checkout origin/origin/feature` and perhaps get that in step 2.

Once you *create* a branch named `origin/feature`, `git checkout` takes that up in step 1.

Because this kind of thing does happen, it's a bad idea for someone to create a branch named `origin/whatever`.  It's also a bad idea to have a remote-tracking name `refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature`, but you don't control this directly: you can only ask or command the Git repository over at `origin` to use a *different name*, such as `refs/heads/feature2`.

#### Fixing the blame and/or the problem

Whoever created the name `origin/feature` as a *branch* name over *on* `origin` is the person at fault.  To fix the *problem*, though, you just need to rename the branch over on `origin`.  This may be easy—perhaps there's a web interface to do that, for instance—or it may be a bit tricky.

Once the branch *on* `origin` has been renamed (to `feature2` or some more meaningful name), run:

```
git fetch --prune
```

to have *your* Git software call up *their* Git software, see their new list of branch names, and *delete* your `refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature` name while also creating the new remote-tracking name based on the new branch name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I cannot claim that I understood everything right now but I got an idea of the problem. I will come back later to dig in a little bit deeper.