# Unconsistent git-checkout of remote branches

Tags: git

*Solution already found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287722/git-checkout-master-does-not-switch-branch-repository-broken)*: The branch name is the same as a folder name in the repository.

I check out a git repo with different branches

```
$ git clone <repo> .
$ git branch -a
* b1
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/b1
  remotes/origin/b1
  remotes/origin/b2
  remotes/origin/b3
```

There's no master branch, the default is `b1`

```
$ cat .git/config
...
[branch "b1"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/b1
```

I am using git version 1.9.1.
According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch) I only need to `git checkout b2` to checkout and track the remote branch `origin/b2` with a local branch `b2`

```
$ git checkout b2
  Branch b2 set up to track remote branch b2 from origin.
  Switched to a new branch 'b2'
```

The branch is added to `.git/config`

But if I try to checkout another branch...

```
$ git checkout b3
```

...nothing happens. No error message, no checkout to the branch `b3`.

I can do

```
$ git checkout -b b3 origin/b3
Branch b3 set up to track remote branch b3 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'b3'
```

What could be the difference between the two branches so that the `checkout` behaves differently?

Could it be with which git version a branch was created/committed/pushed?

*UPDATE*:

The branch names used in this post alias the real branch names (which I'd like to avoid showing here).

A checkout of a non-existing branch shows:

```
$ git checkout invalid_branch
error: pathspec 'invalid_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: Not seeing a `remotes/origin/b3` branch in your list. Just a typo?

Comment: Also, seems odd not to have a remote `HEAD`. I would expect to see `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/b1` if `b1` is the default

Comment: **git checkout -t -b master origin/master** for checkout branch which not present in local.

Comment: @Phil thanks for pointing out, fixed both

Comment: @MaheshGareja I think the point is that OP **should** be able to use `git checkout b3` which is equivalent to `git checkout -b b3 --track origin/b3`

Comment: @radix are there any other remotes? Check with `git remote -v`

Comment: @Phil No, there are no other remotes.

Comment: That's very odd then. You should at least expect to see some messaging or errors. Try starting from scratch (and not cloning into the current directory)

Comment: @Phil that's what I thought, too: **If git can't accomplish the command, it should report some error**. Cloning from scratch with `mkdir new_dir; git clone <url> new_dir` didn't make any difference

Comment: And your output from `git branch -a` above is complete? No editing?

Comment: I've added a comment resp. branch names to the post. I replaced the original branch names (containing company names) with b1, b2, b3 (which is why I had errors in the `git branch -a` output in the first place).

Comment: Weird, I think I just replicated this by following the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287722/git-checkout-master-does-not-switch-branch-repository-broken. Is that the case here, do you have a folder with the same name present? Seems like git has to be tracking files within that folder to see the weird behaviour.

Comment: **Yes. Solved.**! There's a folder with the same name as the branch which git doesn't switch to. Makes my post a duplicate, I'll add it to the post. Only the heading of the other post is quite specific, I even didn't find the thread.

Comment: Super weird bug, I did a naive google search for "git checkout does nothing", seemed like an interesting problem =D